# Best place to install software that will “play nice” inside and outside Docker in Linux?

Tags: linux, installation, docker

In Linux systems, what is the best place to install your own software that will play nice both inside and outside docker containers?

For example, if one wants to install a piece of software called:

```
name="com.hovio.birds.happybirds"
```

Would it be best to install it in:

```
/hovio/birds/happybirds
```

or

```
/opt/hovio/birds/happybirds
```

I suppose outside Docker, `/opt` is better in Linux systems with no root access, [like it is explained here](http://docs.jivesoftware.com/jive/7.0/community_admin/index.jsp?topic=/com.jivesoftware.help.sbs.online/admin/nonroot_install_setup.html).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

In general in Linux/Unix, one does not just drop random directories at root level of a filesystem. A good overview of what is commonly accepted as part of the root filesystem level (`/`) [can be found here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/the-root-directory.html) and is generally as follows with little variation:

```
/bin       Essential command binaries
/boot      Static files of the boot loader
/dev       Device files
/etc       Host-specific system configuration
/lib       Essential shared libraries and kernel modules
/media     Mount point for removeable media
/mnt       Mount point for mounting a filesystem temporarily
/opt       Add-on application software packages
/sbin      Essential system binaries
/srv       Data for services provided by this system
/tmp       Temporary files
/usr       Secondary hierarchy
/var       Variable data
```

While structure that doesn’t explicitly say one *can’t* place their own directory at that level, the *implied* structure basically states, “Hey, don’t place anything here but what fits in the established parent directory structure.”

So knowing that, seeing this idea of a structure in your question:

```
/hovio/birds/happybirds
```

Well that makes my system administrator stomach get queasy. The reason why you don’t do that is root filesystem level (`/`) should only be for directory parent hierarchies. It just gets too confusing and too messy too quickly if you do that for every piece of software you install. You will break something doing that even if you “promise to be careful” over time.

Now placing things in the `/opt` directory is well respected and understood. So this is fine:

```
/opt/hovio/birds/happybirds
```

And it doesn’t necessarily have anything to do with root system access. It’s simply an accepted convention to place system software that doesn’t fit elsewhere into `/opt`. As [explained clearly here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/opt.html):

> This directory is reserved for all the software and add-on packages
>   that are not part of the default installation. For example,
>   StarOffice, Kylix, Netscape Communicator and WordPerfect packages are
>   normally found here. To comply with the FSSTND, all third party
>   applications should be installed in this directory.

This also makes it easier if for any reason someone who is not you needs to assess the system later on. Instead of scratching their head about what role the `/hovio` directory plays, they will know if they see something in `/opt` it’s something of use/importance.